# Date format in Rdlc Report Viewer Changes while printing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, rdlc

In my `.net` desktop application, there is a report and while viewing report it shows `dd/MMM/yy`. But when i click print i am getting the printout as 
`mm/dd/yy`. How can i print it exactly like the system short date settings like `DD/MM/YYYY`

my text box expression is:

```
FormatDateTime(First(Fields!Delivery_Date.Value, "DataSet1"), DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Change Format in Text Box Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ7ud.png)

You can just setting date format in Text Box Properties